# The older official icons and/or theme

Tags: icons, themes, official-repositories

Without success, I started looking for older official themes and icons. I personally do not like the design of 20.04 and are not customer-friendly. I didn't expect them to make such a big change in an LTS. During the upgrade the design changed but does not offer the possibility to restore the old version. Via Tweaks I can change themes and icons but not any old version.

Can anyone help me to install older **official** versions or a shell?

Comment: How much "older"? Which specific Ubuntu version and DE are you talking about?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you have a backup (you do have backups, right?) you can `sudo mv /*backup*/usr/share/icons/yaru /usr/share/icons/yaru` or/and do the same but substitute icons for themes

Comment: Thanks! Now I know where the icons are stored. In an Ubuntu 19.10 I made a copy of Yaru.tar.gz and placed it on the 20.04. Then unpacked it. Then opened via the terminal `sudo nautilus`. In it the name `/usr/share/icons/yaru` name yaru-ould. And finally put the new map Yaru there. Reboot and done. Too bad it has to be this way.